# Blowing up the Grassmannian at a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I want to know what the blow-up of the Grassmannian at a point looks like. Consider $G=Gr(r,n)$ and $V\in G$. I want to understand more explicitly what $Bl_V(G)$ should mean.

Of course for affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$, the blow-up at the origin is a subset of $\mathbb{A}^n\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ defined by $B=\{(x,L)\in \mathbb{A}^n\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}| x\in L\}$. Similarly we can view the blow-up of a point in projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

If we take the viewpoint that the blow-up at a point should be the projectivization of the tangent space, and use the fact that $T_VG = Hom(V,\mathbb{C}^n/V)$, we probably want to describe $Bl_V(G)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{P}(T_VG )\times G$ given by some convenient set of equations. Of course we can always look locally and describe the blow-up that way, but I want something more global. In particular, the map from $Bl_V(G)$ to $G$ should be an isomorphism away from $V$, and only blow-up $V$.

Any references would also be appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, but both blowups and Grassmannians are described by a universal property. So you can probably combine these to get a universal property of the blown up Grassmannian. Giving a morphism from $X$ to the blown up Grassmannian is the same as giving a subbundle of the trivial rank $n$ bundle on $X$ with the property that...

Comment: Another comment: the characterization of blowups of affine and projective spaces is a bit hard to generalize since it implicitly identifies "actual lines through $x$" (i.e. a certain linear series on $X$) with "tangent vectors at $x$". So it more readily generalizes to embeddings of the form $Bl_x(X) \hookrightarrow|L| \times X$ for good linear series $|L|$ (when these exist, anyway).

Comment: I don't know of any general description of the type you're seeking, but (as you're probably aware) the blow-up of projective space at a point is the ruled manifold $$\mathbf{P}\bigl(\mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}\bigr) \simeq \mathbf{P}\bigl(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)\bigr).$$

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on Math Overflow and thanks to Sasha we have an answer:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198840/blowing-up-the-grassmannian-at-a-point